# C++ - char** passed in as function argument, should it be caller allocated or callee?

Tags: c++, pointers

If I have a function like the following:

```
 bool MyFunc(char **outMessage)
 {
 }
```

What is the expectation here? Will the caller allocate a buffer, and pass to the callee? But then what if the callee overruns the buffer?

To be clear thee is no size, or any other argument, this is the function definition. How would you see it?

Or do I have it wrong? It's a callee allocated buffer? But if it's a callee-allocated buffer, how do I dispose the buffer? Note: there is no function to dispose this provided by the library.

EDIT: This is a real scenario, taken from here --> http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Analysis_2Analysis_8cpp_source.html#l00078

Comment: I'd smack whoever wrote this function. On the head. Hard.

Comment: In C++ you would normally use std::string, this is more of a C question, although you can do this in C++ but very not-recommended

Comment: Seriously, though, my guess is that this is callee-allocated, with a `char *` pointing to the allocated buffer containing the message to be stored into `*outMessage`.

Comment: The very fact that you have to guess shows how poor the interface design is.

Comment: Don't downvote yet. The idea is bad, but I think the question is Okay.

Comment: Most likely a NULL terminated C string array, like `argv`. But it's not possible to know unless the *documentation* specifies a contract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I have a function (...)* - where have you taken it from? Is it in some framework? Or within a project?

In such cases, you need to refer to the documentation.

If, for any reason, there is no documentation, try to locate the author (if he's in your company / project) and ask.

If, for any reason, the author is not accessible, refer to the source code - find a usage of this function. Where is it used? How do other use it?

As a last resort, make an assumption. I'd guess you need to set `*outMessage`, namely, the function is called as this:

```
char * msg = NULL;
MyFunc(&msg); // You set it

printf("%s", msg);
```

Anyways, that's bad for C++.

Comment: I've edited the question to add the function I'm talking about, to be honest, it's a highly respected project: LLVM.

Comment: I can't be 100% sure, but this seems to confirm what I've suggested:
`if (OutMessages)
*OutMessages = strdup(MsgsOS.str().c_str());`

Comment: hmm, so i wonder how the caller can de-allocate it? To assume you can call free seems like a dangerous one.

Comment: It does. Even it the pointer is not `NULL`, we can't be sure it's been allocated properly. Unless you find it in the code elsewhere :)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted to understand, and you are also right.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no size argument, then I'd expect `MyFunc` to be responsible for allocating the buffer. Otherwise it's not going to know how large the buffer is!

Ensure that your declaration comments clearly indicate this fact.

But also note that this is not a very good way of doing things. It might fly in C in 1852, but we've moved on from that. Why not accept a `std::string` by reference, or something?

Comment: If MyFunc allocates it, and doesn't provide a way to dispose it? What then?

Comment: @halivingston: What do you mean? That's the case with basically any such function. The documentation will indicate that ownership is passed to the callee and inform you how to free the resource. I'm not saying that this is necessarily "good", but it is conventional when you _are_ accepting a `T**` into a function.